# Accessing the variable from another function of the same class

Tags: python, class, object, methods, scope

```
from folder_exp import my_tcommands as t
class Gravity(EarthG):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Gravity, self).__init__()

    def check(self):
        original = t.get_gravity()
        print "Original gravity from the function:", original
        my_gravity = 9.888
        t.set_gravity(my_gravity)


    def verify(self):
```

I have to load original gravity here in `verify` using `t.set_gravity(original)` but I have already re-written the gravity using `t.set_gravity(my_gravity)` in `check` function hence if I do `t.get_gravity` again, it gives me `9.888 and not the original one`.

What is the way to access `original` from `check` so that I can do the following operation in `verify` method.

```
def verify(self):
    t.set_gravity(original)
```

Comment: make a copy of `original`

Comment: Ohh sorry .. self.original works. I  had some other issue with the program... sorry again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name `original` and, potentially, the object to which it refers disappear once the enclosing function returns. If you want to access it later, you have to create a new name which will not go out of scope so soon.

A convenient place to store it is in the object itself:

```
def check(self):
    self.original = t.get_gravity()
    print "Original gravity from the function:", self.original
    my_gravity = 9.888
    t.set_gravity(my_gravity)
```

A subsequent invocation will see that object:

```
def verify(self):
    t.set_gravity(self.original)
```